# Vertically aligning div inside an inline-block

Tags: html, css

So I have two elements in my page: `center` and `neighbor`.

`center` is centered horizontally in my page, with `neighbor` sitting to the left of it.

`center` is a div that can contain elements of an arbitrary height that I can't personally control. `neighbor` is a div that can contain one or more `<a>` elements (also not something  that I can change) that I need to display horizontally as a row.

Here's my code so far:

```css
.page {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.neighbor {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="center">foo<br>bar<br>oof</div>
    <div class="neighbor">
      <a>first&nbsp;</a>
      <a>second</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, my problem is that I want to vertically center `neighbor` relative to `center`'s height. I tried several aligning attributes such as `align-items`, `vertical-align`, `justify-content`, but none of them helped.

So, is there any way to align `neighbor` the way I wanted to?

Comment: the common `top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);`